# How do we take the limit of this quantum operation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, mathematical-physics, operators, quantum-information

I am wondering how to take the following limit:
\begin{align}
L=  \lim_{\tau \to \infty} \frac{1}{\tau}  \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dy \,   \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} d x \, e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{-i\hat{P} y}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}y},
\end{align}
where $$\rho = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz' \ \rho(z,z') \left|z\right\rangle\!\left\langle z'\right| $$ is a density matrix on the real line, $\hat{P}$ is the momentum operator which generates translations $$e^{-i\hat{P} y} \left|z\right\rangle = \left|z + y\right\rangle .$$

I expect the answer to be $0$, but I don't know how to show it rigorously. From the above expression it's clear the integrand vanishes in the limit $\tau \to \infty$, but I don't know if this implies the entire expression vanishes as well.

I've tried to apply L'Hopital's rule with no success:
\begin{align}
L &=  \lim_{\tau \to \infty}   \frac{1}{\tfrac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dy \,   \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{-i\hat{P}y}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}y}\\
&=  \lim_{\tau \to \infty}  \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[   \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(\tau/2-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{-i\hat{P}\tau/2}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}\tau/2} \\
&\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  -  \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(-\tau/2-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{i\hat{P}\tau/2}  \rho e^{-i\hat{P}\tau/2} \Bigg] \\
&\qquad +  \lim_{\tau \to \infty} \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dy \,   \frac{\partial}{\partial \tau} \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{-i\hat{P}y}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}y}\\
&=  \lim_{\tau \to \infty}  \frac{1}{2} \Bigg[   \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(\tau/2-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{-i\hat{P}\tau/2}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}\tau/2} \\
&\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  -  \left(1 -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dx \, e^{-\frac{(-\tau/2-x)^2}{\sigma^2}}\right)  e^{i\hat{P}\tau/2}  \rho e^{-i\hat{P}\tau/2} \Bigg] \\
&\qquad -  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \pi} \sigma } \lim_{\tau \to \infty} \int_{-\tau/2}^{\tau/2} dy \,  \left[ \frac{1}{2}  e^{-\frac{(y-\tau/2)^2}{\sigma^2}} - \frac{1}{2}  e^{-\frac{(y+\tau/2)^2}{\sigma^2}}  \right]e^{-i\hat{P}y}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}y}.
\end{align}
One might be able to argue that the first two terms in the square brackets in the last equality above vanish, by using the limit law: $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x) \lim_{x \to a} g(x),$$ but that assumes that both the limits, $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) $; in this case it's not clear if $$\lim_{\tau \to \infty} e^{-i\hat{P}\tau/2}  \rho e^{i\hat{P}\tau/2}$$ exists.

Comment: From a quick glance, I'd say that you should Fourier transform the whole thing. This should turn the convolution into a multiplication, half of which is a Gaussian integral and thus well-known. Also, the Fourier transform of the momentum operator, which should allow you to tackle the other term.

Comment: @Martin 

That’s a good idea! However, after taking the Fourier transform, to get a product of Fourier transforms of the two functions we would have to apply the convolution theorem. Doesn't the convolution theorem only hold in the limit $\tau \to \infty$?

Comment: This question lacks physical context, as it stands, it is a pure math question about how to evaluate a limit.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I partially agree. The limit arises when trying to perform a G-twirl, that is, a weighted average of a density matrix over a group $G$, in this case the group of translations. The G-twirl is well defined for compact groups, however in this case we are averaging over the group of translations which is non-compact. $\tau$ is the range of possible translations, which I am trying to take to infinity. Physically, the G-twirl describes the a state when you lack a reference frame associated with $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. ( I give absolutely no guarantee about not making calculational
mistakes!)

\begin{eqnarray*}
L(\tau ) &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\left( 1-\frac{1}{
\sqrt{\pi }\sigma }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dx\exp [-\frac{(y-x)^{2}}{
\sigma ^{2}}]\right) e^{-iPy}\rho e^{+iPy}=L_{1}(\tau )-L_{2}(\tau ) \\
L_{1}(\tau ) &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dye^{-iPy}\rho
e^{+iPy} \\
L_{2}(\tau ) &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{1}{\sqrt{
\pi }\sigma }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dx\exp [-\frac{(y-x)^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}
]e^{-iPy}\rho e^{+iPy}
\end{eqnarray*}
Take matrix elements with momentum eigenstates of $P$, assuming that $
<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}>$ exists. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
&<&p_{1}|L_{1}(\tau )|p_{2}>=\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau
/2}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}>=<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}>\frac{1}{
\tau }\left[ \frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\right] _{y=-\tau
/2}^{y=+\tau /2} \\
&=&<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}>\frac{1}{\tau }\frac{1}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}
\{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}-e^{+i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}\}=\frac{2}{\tau }
\frac{1}{(p_{1}-p_{2})}\sin \{(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2\}<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}> \\
&=&\frac{\sin \{(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2\}}{(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}<p_{1}|\rho
|p_{2}>\rightarrow \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & p_{1}\neq p_{2} \\
<p_{1}|\rho |p_{1}> & p_{1}=p_{2}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray*}

Next

\begin{eqnarray*}
&<&p_{1}|L_{2}(\tau )|p_{2}>=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }\sigma }\frac{1}{\tau }
\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau
/2}dx\exp [-\frac{(y-x)^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}> \\
&=&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }\sigma }<p_{1}|\rho |p_{2}>\frac{1}{\tau }
\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}\int_{-\tau /2-y}^{+\tau
/2-y}dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]
\end{eqnarray*}
and do a partial integration

\begin{eqnarray*}
J(\tau ) &=&\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}\int_{-\tau
/2-y}^{+\tau /2-y}dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}] \\
&=&\left[ \frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\int_{-\tau
/2-y}^{+\tau /2-y}dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]\right] _{y=-\tau
/2}^{y=+\tau /2}+\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{
-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\{-e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}}+e^{-(y+\tau /2)^{2}}\} \\
&=&\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\int_{-\tau }^{0}dx\exp
[-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]-\frac{e^{+i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}}{
-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\int_{-\tau }^{0}dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}] \\
&&+\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}
\{-e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}}+e^{-(y+\tau /2)^{2}}\} \\
&=&\frac{1}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau
/2}-e^{+i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}\}\int_{0}^{\tau }dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma
^{2}}] \\
&&+\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}
\{-e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}}+e^{-(y+\tau /2)^{2}}\} \\
&=&\frac{2\sin (p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}{p_{1}-p_{2}}\int_{0}^{\tau }dx\exp [-
\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]+\int_{-\tau /2}^{\\+\tau /2}dy\frac{
e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\{-e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}}\\+e^{-(y+\tau
/2)^{2}}\}
\end{eqnarray*}
Let

\begin{eqnarray*}
X(\tau ) &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\frac{2\sin (p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}{p_{1}-p_{2}}
\int_{0}^{\tau }dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}]=\frac{2\sin
(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}{p_{1}-p_{2}}\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{0}^{\tau }dx\exp [-
\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}] \\
p_{1} &=&p_{2}\Rightarrow X=\int_{0}^{\tau }dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}
}]\rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty }dx\exp [-\frac{x^{2}}{\sigma ^{2}}] \\
p_{1} &\neq &p_{2}\Rightarrow X\rightarrow 0
\end{eqnarray*}
The remaining term
\begin{equation*}
Y(\tau )=\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{
e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\{-e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}}+e^{-(y+\tau
/2)^{2}}\}
\end{equation*}
is harder. The two parts are

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{
-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}e^{-(y-\tau /2)^{2}} &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau }^{0}dy
\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})(y+\tau /2}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}e^{-y^{2}}\\=\frac{
e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau
}^{0}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}e^{-y^{2}} \\
\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{-\tau /2}^{+\tau /2}dy\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}}{
-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}e^{-(y+\tau /2)^{2}} &=&\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{0}^{+\tau }dy
\frac{e^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})(y-\tau /2)}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}e^{-y^{2}}\\=\frac{
e^{+i(p_{1}-p_{2})\tau /2}}{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})}\frac{1}{\tau }\int_{0}^{+\tau
}dye^{-i(p_{1}-p_{2})y}e^{-y^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Again we have to distinguish between $p_{1}=p_{2}$ and $p_{1}\neq p_{2}$. In
the second case these objects tends to $0$. I leave the first case to you.
It seems your guess is correct for $p_{1}\neq p_{2}$.